# Find if string is in other string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string that contain words.

```
string attrs = "AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD"
```

and i have List of objects that i want to check if one of the objects exist in this string, and if not then filter out this object

```
List<Vehicle> vehiclesSort = new List<Vehicle>();
```

so i tried to do something like this:

```
vehiclesSort = vehiclesSort.Where(o => o.Class.Contains(attrs))
```

but got compile error,

moreover i need to check if Class property exist in attrs, and not if attrs exist in Class property so i think that im not in the right direction

please assist,

Comment: `but got compile error,` What **specifically** was the error? On what line?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: what's the data type of Class for Vehicle...a string?

Comment: attrs itself needs to be a list...maybe a lookup so you can search it...use string.split to get an array...then do a tolookup on it to get something quickly searchable

Comment: *so i think that im not in the right direction* ... not sure unless you explicitly tell us which direction you are heading to (i.e, post the relevant code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this

```html
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string attrs = "AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD";
            List<Vehicle> vehiclesSort = new List<Vehicle>();
            vehiclesSort.Add(new Vehicle(attrs));
            vehiclesSort.Add(new Vehicle("bbb"));
            vehiclesSort = vehiclesSort.Where(o => o.attr.Contains(attrs)).ToList();

            foreach (var VARIABLE in vehiclesSort)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE.attr);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Vehicle
    {
        public Vehicle(string attr1)
        {
            this.attr = attr1;
        }

        public string attr;
    }
```

Comment: @user9127893 does this solution even work. I tested it and i get one item in the `vehiclesSort` list that is equal to `"AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD"`???

Answer (score 2):

I modified your query a little bit. Here is an example:

```
List<Vehicle> vehiclesSort = new List<Vehicle>()
{
    new Vehicle() {Class="VW" },
    new Vehicle() {Class="BBB" },
    new Vehicle() {Class="BMW" },
    new Vehicle() {Class="DDD" },
    new Vehicle() {Class="AUDI" },
};

string attrs = "AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD";

vehiclesSort = vehiclesSort.Where(x => attrs.Split(',').Contains(x.Class)).ToList();
```

`Vehicle` class:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string Class { get; set; }
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N7qzgl)**

Comment: Won't this try to split the `attrs` over and over for every vehicle?